# Why VideoCapture doesn't work in member functions?

Tags: c++, opencv, pthreads

I spent some hours trying to read cv::VideoCapture frames from member Thread with a member function of the same class. All usual code of creating, read and imshow() was in this member function.

I thought the problem was in Thread but I make some test code and find out it in a member function.

That test code:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "myclass.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    myclass m;
    m.run();

    return 0;
}
```

**myclass.hpp**

```
class myclass
{
public:
    myclass();
    virtual ~myclass();

    void run();
};
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "myclass.hpp"

myclass::myclass()
{
}

myclass::~myclass()
{
}

void myclass::run()
{
    cv::VideoCapture capture(0);
    cv::Mat frame;

    while(true)
    {
        capture.read(frame);
        cv::imshow("TEST", frame);
    }
    capture.release();
}
```

Compiles OK, but didn't work properly. It shows empty "TEST" window.

Why doesn't work cv::VideoCapture::read(cv::Mat) in bember functions?

PS: opencv v3.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to reference about [imshow](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563)

> This function should be followed by cv::waitKey function which displays the image for specified milliseconds. **Otherwise, it won't display the image**.

just add the call of `waitKey()` function

```
capture.read(frame);
cv::imshow("TEST", frame);
cv::waitKey(25);
```

Comment: I thought waitKey() belongs to the imshow() and it is OK to place it in Thread function of one class and VideoCapture::read(Mat) to place in member function of another class without waitKey(). I just move waitKey() from Thread class function to reader class function right after read(Mat). And it works now.